# Find all solution of a Quadratic Congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find all solution of $x^2 \equiv a \pmod {11^2}$, for every $a \in Q_{11}$.

I'm not sure what's the question actually asking. Do I need to find all the quadratic residues of $\pmod {11^2}$ or find all solution which in a form of $x \equiv {something} \pmod {something}$?

As far as I know,

$11$ is a prime, so $\phi(11) = 10$.

$|Q_{11}| = \frac{\phi(11)}{2} = \frac{10}{2} = 5$. $Q_{11} = \{1,3,4,5,9\}$.

In order to find solution for $\pmod {11^2}$, we first need to make sure it has a solution for $\pmod {11}$. But then I fall back to the initial question again, do the quadratic residues actually serve as a solution??

Thanks!!

Comment: Er....what is $\,Q_{11}\,$ for you?

Comment: Set of quadratic residue created by $\pmod{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notation, we get

$$Q_{11}:=\{0,1,3,4,5,9\}$$

Using [Hensel's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) (in particular its proof), putting $\,f(x)=x^2-a\,\,\,,\,\,a\in Q_{11}$, we get for example with $\,a=5\,\;,\;\;r=4$ (we make arithmetic modulo $\,11\,$) :

$$t:=-\frac{f(4)}{11}(f'(4))^{-1}=-\frac{11}{11}8^{-1}=-8^{-1}=-7=4\implies$$

$$s=4+4\cdot 11=48\;,\;\;\text{ and indeed}\;\;48^2=5\pmod{121=11^2}$$

Now you do the above for each square root of the quadratic residues..

Comment: Where do the $s$ and $t$ come from?

Comment: Check the link I wrote you: it's part of Hensel's Lemma's proof.